# Magento admin failing to load CSS when SSL is activated

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, javascript, css, ssl

I've activated SSL for the whole Magento store and it works perfectly on the frontend, but the issues I'm having is with the admin.

Once enabled, I can't access it.

Before I had an issue with **`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`** and fixed it by adding to my **`.htaccess`** this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

And it fixed the redirect issue. But now I can't use it because the site is broken.

I suppose the issue is because, the *CSS/JS* are still being loaded via HTTP.

How can I change it (manually or programmatically)?

**UPDATE**:

Is there a way to simply ignore the Admin(backoffice)?

If I set: **Unsecure** to **https** it automatically does apply the config for admin as well... It ignores the setting in *Secure -> Use Secure URLs in Admin -> No*

**Could it be Re-Indexing problem?**

Answer (score 7):

This issue is probably being caused because the admin portal is attempting to load the javascript and css files via normal http, as opposed to https.

To correct this, please try to set **Use Secure URLs in Admin** to true, in ***System -> Config -> General -> Web***.

**UPDATE In Magento 2.4:**

To correct this, please try to set **Use Secure URLs in Admin** to true, in ***Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web***.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Hello David, 

Thank you for your input. 
In my database i have: scope_id: 1, web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1 and enabled in the backend... Still giving me problems...

Comment: When you open F12 developer tools and visit console, are you getting insecure or mixed content warnings? If so, is it for the files that aren't loading?

Comment: Also, did you apply that rule to .htaccess before or after you set the secure url rule in Admin? What about using secure URLs in frontend? Was that checked before or after your htaccess rule?

Comment: I can't tell, before or after. Can you tell me when it should be done? I do the following: Go to admin and set the SLL for frontend (unsecure and secure), then apply uncomment the .htaccess rule and manually clean all var/cache and var/sessions

And yes, I get mixed content (insecure) warning's in the frontend, because I need to revise all my links and images in the content. But first I want to fix this :) Thanks for your input. Realy appreciate it.

Comment: Does it actually say ``https://domain.com`` in your .htaccess file? Or did you replace your actual domain with domain.com?

Comment: Offcourse not :) In my config, my domain is instead of domain.com

Answer (score 0):

This is an update post for David Lerned answer.

In Magento 2.4 there where a couple layout changes including the settings now being under `Stores` instead of `System`: `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web`

There are a couple settings that could be causing the issue:

1. `Auto-Redirect to Base URL` is ON. This setting redirects the base url to the `www` version of it which can cause issues if a `www` version doesn't exist. Find this setting in `Url Options`.
2. Check that `Use Secure URLs on Storefront` and `Use Secure URLs in Admin` are both off. Find this setting in `Base URLs (Secure)`.