# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Admin Backend

Tags: magento2

I seem to be having a problem with my website roofmegastore.co.uk

The actual website works, however, when I try to access the admin page it comes up ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I checked env.php and the backend URL is definitely the same one as I had since the beginning. Any possible solutions to this?

Comment: go through once to this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/magento-2-error-err-too-many-redirects

Comment: The config solution worked on the page you linked, thank you!