# "Your session has expired" - Magento 2.2.7 fresh install

Tags: magento2, validation

I've started out with Magento 2. Everything's working fine, except for Magento's `formKeyValidator` which isn't able to validate the incoming request. It's happening on the frontend.

While adding a product to the cart or creating an account. This isn't passing::

```
// module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php - function execute()
$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())
```

I've increased the cookie lifetime, set the valid domain, and path ( http://localhost/mysite, `domain:localhost`, `path:/mysite`  ) from the backend config panel, yet for some reason I keep getting this:

"Your session has expired"

Comment: I had the same problem. This case solved the problem.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94956/74419

Comment: where to write thse two lines of code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved it the same day when I fist posted it. This answer might help others.

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: Thanks @jean works for me

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Disable the cache 
Steps 2: Run below two lines of Mysql code

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/yourmagentofolder/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/yourmagentofolder/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```