# Admin panel lookweird because of the many redirects in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, redirect, admin-panel

I am not getting a normal admin screen. Looking with **console** I am getting these errors:

> (index):30 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):17 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):18 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):19 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Ebizmarts_MailChimp/css/styles.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):20 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mollie_Payment/css/styles.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):21 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Ves_All/css/styles.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):22 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Ves_Brand/css/styles.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):23 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):24 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):28 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):29 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):35 Uncaught TypeError:
>   require.config is not a function
>       at (index):35 (anonymous) @ (index):35 (index):59 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
>       at (index):59 (anonymous) @ (index):59 ial.js:3219 registerEventsMessage called  ial.js:4459 ready: before call parse for
>   last time {timer: null, count: 0, error: true, data: null,
>   parsedOnReady: false, …} (index):108 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/magento-logo.svg
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 2favicon.ico:1 GET
>   https://www.bakmans.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/magento-2-error-err-too-many-redirects

Comment: Seems it will be mod rewrite issue for wrong HTTPS configuration

Comment: I tried everything in the link you gave, but no luck,