# I am getting too many redirect issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, page

why I am getting too many redirect issue in Magento 2.3, PHP 7.1
I have tried almost each and everything whatever described in the Magento stack exchange, Github, Magento community etc but still I am getting error 
**run all commands 
permissions set**
from **core_config_data tried admin_html = 0 and even 1** 
tried almost each and everything but still the same issue and the most important thing I have cleared the cache of browser **cleared cookies and Magento cache also** 
[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/magento-2-error-err-too-many-redirects

Comment: Have you try to fresh instalation? or custom theme or what?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya site was already working , i have just changed the domain ... frontend is working backend is not working .... i think i did a mistake to change the default dns but i dont understand how to revert it back without admin acces

Comment: Confirm you have enter proper URL into core_config_table from database?

Comment: yes confirmed so many times