# Magento Frontend ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after fresh install

Tags: magento2, xampp, windows10

I am new to Magento this is the first time installing it but I have been stuck on this issue for two days now.

I have windows 10 OS, and Laragon for apache and MySQl, Laragon is just like XAAMP no big difference.

I installed Magento 2.4 using composer

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2New
```

Then I followed the exact tutorial in this [link](https://www.thecoachsmb.com/6-steps-to-install-magento-2-4-3-on-xampp-windows-using-composer/#comment-200). And everything mentioned in the tutorial like errors and messages appeared to me and solved it like mentioned in tutorial.

Finally when done I open frontend URL `http://alaa.magento2new.test/` and it gives me the `Too many redirects` error, so I tried `http://alaa.magento2new.test/admin` and it worked like a charm and logged in to admin dashboard successfully.

I tried too many things nothing worked, like finally I enabled SSL in apache and Magento and still the same problem, and I almost tried every solution in this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/magento-2-error-err-too-many-redirects?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) with no luck, and many other threads online.

This is the current config in my db after changing and modifying from the fresh install
[image]

My final thoughts now is installing a virtualbox with Linux image or use docker container, but I would really be happy if I can run magneto with my current environment.

Comment: Please checkout this link about system requirements for magento -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Comment: I know it's not supported on windows directly but many people use it

Comment: anyway on windows do you recommend using docker or VM ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : you can't make it work on your current environment

> Operating systems (Linux x86-64)
> Linux distributions, such as RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, and similar. Magento is not supported on Microsoft Windows and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have both web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url in core_config_data table and run php bin/magento cache:flush