# I am unable to login to site and the admin e.g.example.com/admin due to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Tags: magento2, redirect

I am unable to login to site and admin in my website e.g. example.com/admin due to  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

```
This page isn’t working
    example.com redirected you too many times.
    Try clearing your cookies.
    ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I am using Amazon Lightsail host. How do I access admin using localhost , creating a tunnel, like the one for PHPMyAdmin? This is not using my domain name.

Answer (score 0):

i think this issues is database so you try this

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS :

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84756/50635**

To correct this, please try to set Use Secure URLs in Admin to true, in System -> Config -> General -> Web.

Or with database access, change following record value to 1 :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%web/secure/use_in_adminhtml%';
```

And more refer this link :-

**[Magento 2 Error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/magento-2-error-err-too-many-redirects)**