# magento 2 cloud docker setup for 2.4.3-p1 failed gives error

Tags: magento2, setup, magento2-cloud, magento-cloud, cloud-docker

I am trying to setup magento2.4.3-p1 with cloud docker when I run the `docker.sh` command

curl -sL https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud-docker/releases/download/1.2.0/init-docker.sh | bash -s -- --php 7.4

it gives error

Problem 1
- web-token/jwt-framework v2.2.11 requires ext-sodium * -> the requested PHP extension sodium is missing from your system.
- web-token/jwt-framework v2.2.11 requires ext-sodium * -> the requested PHP extension sodium is missing from your system.
- Installation request for web-token/jwt-framework v2.2.11 -> satisfiable by web-token/jwt-framework[v2.2.11].

Please anyone help suggest to me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem manipulating databases, this answer resolved my problem ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84756/50635

To correct this, please try to set Use Secure URLs in Admin to true, in System -> Config -> General -> Web.

Or with database access, change following record value to 1:

> SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like
> '%web/secure/use_in_adminhtml%';

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have already visit it but issue are not resolved